# Обойти форму авторизации

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такая форма авторизации

```
            <form id="an-login-form" method="post" class="sky-form boxed" autocomplete="off">
                <header class="nomargin">
                    <span class='an-login-title'>
          <span>Mscloud</span> <span></span><sup></sup>

                    </span>
                    <div id="an-settings-toggle" class="pull-right" title="STR_SETTINGS">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <fieldset>
                    <section>
                        <label class="input">
          <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Пользователь" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none"
          autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
        </label>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <label class="input">
          <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
          <input id="password" name="html password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" autocomplete="off" />
        </label>
                    </section>
                </fieldset>

                <footer>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Подключение</button>
                </footer>

            </form>
```

После нажатия вызывается js код

vm.marvel-cloud.com/AccessNow/src/accessnow.min.js

Я пытаюсь убрать окно авторизации, что бы после открытия страницы оно сразу авторизировалось фиксированным логином и паролем.
После нажатия кнопки "Подключение" я отслеживаю запрос, и там пусто...
Я мониторил консоль лог, из него видно, что запрос идет к данному js файлу. Я пытался проанализировать в каком месте обрабатывается нажатие кнопки но не могу найти это место.

Comment: а где в приведенной разметке кнопка "войти"?

Comment: "Подключение" ссори

Comment: по кнопке отправка формы и страница перезагружается